# Is there a better way to split MySQL GROUP_CONCAT output into multiple rows? for example say after every six (6) record

Tags: mysql, mariadb, rows, group-concat, mariadb-10.1

I have successfully achieved this scenario below:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(coursecode) 
    FROM (
    SELECT coursecode FROM Table18
    WHERE regno = 'StudentXYZ' AND (ca_score + exam_score) <= 39

    UNION  

    SELECT coursecode FROM Table17
    WHERE regno = 'StudentXYZ' AND (ca_score + exam_score) <= 39
) s

WHERE coursecode 
NOT IN (
    SELECT coursecode 
    FROM Table18
    WHERE regno = 'StudentXYZ' 
    AND (ca_score + exam_score) >= 40

    UNION

    SELECT coursecode 
    FROM Table17
    WHERE regno = 'StudentXYZ' 
    AND (ca_score + exam_score) >= 40
    )
```

This works great!
Here is the sample result below:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GROUP_CONCAT(coursecode)                                                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| EDU222,EDU497,POS302,POS405,POS420,EDU224,EDU311,EDU312,EDU313,GST304,GST305,POS304,POS305,POS308,POS309 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But this is what I desire to achieve:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| GROUP_CONCAT(coursecode)                        |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| EDU222, EDU497, POS302, POS405, POS420, EDU224, |
| EDU311, EDU312, EDU313, GST304, GST305, POS304, |
| POS305, POS308, POS309                          |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Any suggestions? or better-way to solve this challenge?

Comment: which mysql version you are using?

Comment: Hi @SebastianBrosch

 10.1.32-MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following (*supporting MySQL 5.7 / MariaDB < 10.2*):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(coursecode)
FROM (
    SELECT coursecode, @gn:=@gn+1, CEIL(@gn / 6) gn
    FROM (
        SELECT coursecode FROM Table18
        WHERE regno = 'StudentXYZ' AND (ca_score + exam_score) <= 39

        UNION  

        SELECT coursecode FROM Table17
        WHERE regno = 'StudentXYZ' AND (ca_score + exam_score) <= 39
    ) s, (SELECT @gn:=0)gn
    WHERE coursecode NOT IN (
        SELECT coursecode 
        FROM Table18
        WHERE regno = 'StudentXYZ' AND (ca_score + exam_score) >= 40

        UNION

        SELECT coursecode 
        FROM Table17
        WHERE regno = 'StudentXYZ' AND (ca_score + exam_score) >= 40
    )
) group_view GROUP BY group_view.gn
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a23410481633f2ed8b0d8b8e20cf9166)

Since MySQL 8.0 / MariaDB 10.2 you can use the same logic, but with [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) instead of the variable. So your query can look like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(coursecode)
FROM (
    SELECT coursecode, CEIL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY code ASC) / 6) gn
    FROM (
        SELECT coursecode FROM Table18
        WHERE regno = 'StudentXYZ' AND (ca_score + exam_score) <= 39

        UNION  

        SELECT coursecode FROM Table17
        WHERE regno = 'StudentXYZ' AND (ca_score + exam_score) <= 39
    ) s
    WHERE coursecode NOT IN (
        SELECT coursecode 
        FROM Table18
        WHERE regno = 'StudentXYZ' AND (ca_score + exam_score) >= 40

        UNION

        SELECT coursecode 
        FROM Table17
        WHERE regno = 'StudentXYZ' AND (ca_score + exam_score) >= 40
    )
) group_view GROUP BY group_view.gn
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=088476b56ec55a92685c3958a25a2863)

Comment: Awesome @Sebastian ... **It works like MAGIC** - thank you. How can one send a `virtual hug` on stackoverflow? Lol... Great work!

Comment: @AderogbaOtunla - you are welcome! Just vote and accept the answer :D